# Using pymongo with Apache Spark

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-spark, pymongo

I have a Pyspark job that needs to read some configurations from a document stored in MongoDB. I am trying to use pymongo library to read this single document without success and with the following error returned:

AttributeError: module 'pymongo' has no attribute 'MongoClient'

I am using Python 3.6.8 and the latest pymongo available (4.1.1) for this Python release.

Here is my code:

```
import pymongo

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://user:pass@host:port/")
mydb = myclient["db"]
mycol = mydb["last_ingestion"]

myquery = {}

mydoc = mycol.find(myquery)

for x in mydoc:
  print(x)
```

And here is my spark submit command:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --conf spark.yarn.principal=principal--conf spark.yarn.keytab=path/to/keytab --driver-memory 2G --num-executors 2 --executor-cores 2 --executor-memory 2G --py-files /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo.zip prova.py
```

Can anyone help me? I also tried with different version of pymongo